# angular ui router notify false and state go apply twice the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Like I saw there is a bug.

I have a page with 2 parameters (id and tab)

This is my route:

```
.state('app.questionnaire.edit', {
      url: "/:id?:tab",
      templateUrl: "/Content/angular/app/templates/questionnaire-edit.html",
      //reloadOnSearch: false
      })
```

I want when changing the tab the page does not need to reload
But when changing the "id" parameter  than reload the page.

The change tab click event:

```
$scope.changeTab = function (tab) {
    $state.go(".", { tab: tab }, {
        location: 'replace', //  update url and replace
        inherit: false,
        notify: false
    });
    $scope.selectedTab = tab;
}
```

The save click event:

```
 $state.transitionTo('app.questionnaire.edit', { id: response, tab: 2 });
```

My problem is that on save the controller run twice.
I found many posts on this issue , But I do not resolve  my Problem.